# Reason of why OLAP in HBase is possible

Tags: hadoop, hbase, olap, nosql

OLAP directly upon most of the noSQL databases is not possible, but from what I researched it's actually possible in HBase, so I was wondering what features does HBase have in particular that distinguishes it from the others allowing us to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write lots of data processing logic in your application layer to accomplish this. Hbase is a Data store not a DBMS. So yes as long as the data goes in, you can get it out and process it in your application layer however you want.

If this proves inconvenient for you and a nosql platform that supports SQL for OLAP is desirable, you could try [Amisa Server](http://www.amisalabs.com/)